# Matter.js Collision Detection For Player Jumping

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am currently developing a side-scrolling platformer game using Matter.js. However, I'm encountering issues with the collision detection feature. I need assistance with creating a collision detector that can determine if the player is touching any object in the game.

Currently, I have a detector that uses the following code:

```js
Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
  event.pairs.forEach(pair => {
    if (pair.bodyA.label === 'foot' || pair.bodyB.label === 'foot') {
      touchingWall = true;
    }  
  });
});

Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionEnd', function(event) {
  touchingWall = false;
});
```

Note that `'foot'` refers to a smaller hitbox placed below the player's cube, which prevents a bug where the player is launched into the air if they are close to a wall.

While the code currently works, there are multiple issues with it. It stops working when I add cubes ( not static ) to the game. Can you help me with this problem?

*If you wish to view what i currently have, here is a link to my github repo: https://github.com/MemeCake789/Delta*

What I have right now is functional, but I need to modify the code to enable the player to jump only when they are on top of a surface, and disable the jumping ability when they are in mid-air or not in contact with any surface.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in the question itself? External links go down over time, making the question less useful to future visitors. You can make a runnable MJS [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). It sounds like you need to check for collisions with certain types of objects, and not other types? You can use labels or data structures, as best fits your use case.

Comment: When you do post your code, please include the cubes that cause the problem you're concerned about. I don't see them in your GH repo, which more or less appears to run OK. `Matter.Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {` should not be inside the game loop--that's a one-time event creation, and set in a loop causes a memory leak. Setting velocity is also not a great idea, since it bypasses the physics engine. `World.` is deprecated in MJS 0.19, which you're using.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.